# "rip off" x "rip out"

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

I would like to know the difference between these two terms, and whether they are interchangeable or not. Here are two examples that have the same meaning for me:

"Someone has ripped out the first three pages of this book." 
"I will rip your head off!"

"Rip" implies to say that someone is going to tear something off. Since both sentences are talking about something being tore off, for instance: Someone ripped my head off, but not only ripped it and made a wound, but also cut it off my neck, it means my neck no longer has a head, it was cut off.
So, "out" and "off" implies to say the same thing, why then are there two forms? Do they have different meanings? For instance "rip off" means ripping something off savagely, while "rip out" means ripping something off not so savagely?
Or "rip off" doesn't mean "cut my head off my neck" but means only make a wound, while "rip out" means to cut my head off?

Could anyone explain me the difference between them and tell me whether they are interchangeable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "rip off" and "rip out" can mean "to remove". However, there's a connotation of:

- **rip out**: to remove something contained *within* something
- **rip off**: to remove something *on* something.

Examples:

- I will *rip off* your head (on your shoulders)
- I will *rip out* your kidneys (in your abdomen)
- I will *rip off* this sticker (on this page)
- I will *rip out* these pages (in this book)
- I will *rip off* the doors (on your car)
- I will *rip out* the seats (in your car)

Side-note: *rip off* also have a completely different informal meaning: to cheat/steal. ("I paid $20 for this crap t-shirt? What a rip off!" or "The intro of 'Ice Ice Baby' is the same as Queen's 'Under Pressure,' they totally ripped off Queen.")

Comment: So you mean, if something is placed inside something, like: My heart is placed inside my body, it would be "out" ?

Comment: I am uncertain that this is an unambiguous rule, but also in that case it would definitely be "rip out (my heart)"

Comment: But in most cases, would it make a quite big difference if I used them "out" or "off"? I mean, would it be a quite BIG deal? If I said:

Comment: I will rip your head out of your neck!
I will rip your head off your neck!
Would it be a quite big deal if I said it both ways? Or it is a normal thing that natives don't care about?

Comment: "rip your head out of your neck" sounds very odd, as a native speaker. I suppose it's intuitive what you mean, but a native speaker would not say that and if you submitted it in an essay, it would certainly get corrected.

Comment: If you were to say, "I ripped off these pages in this book" i would not think you removed them from the book, i would have thought you plaigerized them, in the context of 'to cheat/steal'

Comment: But if I said: "I ripped off these pages from this book" Would it sound correct now?

Comment: no, for me that doesnt change the meaning of the sentence.