# You removed 1 page of your spiral notebook, what would you say: "I ripped/pulled/tore the page apart" or "I ripped/pulled/tore the page off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-request, phrasal-verbs

[image: page being torn out of a spiral bound notebook]

You removed 1 page of your spiral notebook (**note**: each page can be separated easily by pulling), what would you say:

"**I ripped/pulled/tore the page apart**" or "**I ripped/pulled/tore the page off**" or "**I ripped/pulled/tore the page out**"?

Comment: This should be helpful: [Rip off or Rip out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113383/rip-off-x-rip-out?rq=1). "apart" sounds a bit extreme for just taking out one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrasal verbs with "up" tend to mean "completely".  So "tear up" means to tear into many small pieces.

Tear apart is tear into large pieces. That is what, for example, hyenas do to a carcass. It suggests violence.

"Tear off" is possible, but most likely is "Tear out", since the sheet comes out of book, instead of off a larger piece of paper.

You could tear off a corner. Or tear out a sheet to give to your friend. Or tear up a sheet that you made a big mistake on and don't want anyone to see. And if you get very angry you could tear apart the whole book and throw the pieces out the window.